# Maximo REST query parameter _uw

Tags: rest, parameters, maximo

Can anyone provide me with an example of a REST call using the query parameter _uw?  What is the syntax?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure as to which version of Maximo you may be running, but if you are on 7.6.0.2 or higher, I would very much recommend using the newer JSON API, as you can create saved queries and execute them or use the updated `oslc.where` parameter. You can find that documentation [here](https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html).

However, if that is not an option the `_uw` parameter is fairly similar to a where clause in the Maximo UI. There are a few caveats simply because of the fact that it needs to be entered in the URL and therefore should be URL safe.

**Example**

`<your maximo server>/maxrest/rest/os/mxwo?_uw=wonum IN ('1000','1001')`

Keep in mind URL encoding will likely be necessary if you are making this request outside of the browser.

Comment: Thank you this works great for attributes on the primary object of the OS, but I also need criteria on attributes in child objects.  How would you do that?

Comment: I forgot to specify that I am on 7.5.0.6

Comment: I don't believe there is a way to do this in the older API. Best thing I could recommend would be to handle the filtering client side (if your use case allows for that.)